# swift UITest: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I am running the UITest for my swift project, after i click a `UITextField` it generated this code:

```
let secureTextField = app.secureTextFields["\U5bc6\U7801"]
secureTextField.tap()
```

The error is

> `/XXXUITests.swift:46:60: Invalid escape sequence in literal`,

then i searched and changed `["\U5bc6\U7801"]` to `["\u{5bc6}\u{7801}"]`, i got the error

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Any help?

Comment: @MartinR i think you even don't read my question carefully, i saw that question before, the solution doesn't work.

Comment: If you read that question before then it would be helpful to add that information (with a link) to your question.

Comment: It works for me after that change. On which line exactly do you get the error message about the missing argument?

Comment: Still the same line thank you, i removed all the code and re-generated it again, it works for me know. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just not sure why i re-generated the code the error disappeared.